# Any application can't execute this option - input type="file"

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Previously I could add the path of an image after converting it to Base64 even Input to then be shown in a DIV, but after a while in trying to perform the process does not allow me to do that action and I get the following message:

[image: image error]

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu)
    .directive('pickFile', pickFile)
    .factory('obtenerPerfilEstu', obtenerPerfilEstu);


mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $element) {

    var Perfil, Mes, Periodo_Estu, input, button, evtHandler, dataImage;

    dataImage = localStorage.getItem("imgData");

    if (dataImage === null) {
        $scope.dataImage = "img/profile_icon.png";
    } else {
        $scope.dataImage = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage;
    }

    $scope.loadImage = function (file) {

        if (file.type.indexOf('image') < 0) {
            $scope.res = "Tipo inválido";
            $scope.$apply();
            return;
        }

        var fReader = new FileReader();

        fReader.onload = function () {

            var data = fReader.result;
            $scope.dataImage = data;
            $scope.res = "";
            $scope.$apply();
            localStorage.setItem("imgData", data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpe?g);base64,/, ""));

        };

        fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

};

function pickFile() {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            onselected: "&"
        },

        template: '<button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round pull-right">' +
        '<input type="file" style="display: none !important">' +
        '</button>',

        link: function ($scope, $element) {
              var input = $element.find('input');
              var button = $element.find('button');

            var evtHandler = function () {
                input[0].click();
            };

            button.on('click', evtHandler)
            input.on('change', function () {
                var file = input[0].files[0];
                $scope.onselected({
                    file: file
                });
            });
        }

    };

};
```

Android version in my smartphone is 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Came across this plugin. Looks like it will do the job.

https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-filepickerio/blob/master/README.md

**Original**

Input type=file is not supported in Cordova.

You will have to use something like the Cordova File Plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Along with the Cordova File Transfer Plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

If you just want to select images or pictures you can use the Cordova Camera Plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Using this you can enable users to select an image from their photo library. This will be passed back to the app and you can use the file transfer plugin to send the image to a server.

Install camera plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Sample camera plugin JS code:

```
var cameraOptions = {

    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}

function cameraSuccess(data){

    console.log(data);

    var img = document.getElementById("yourImg");

    img.src = data;

}

function cameraError(error){

    console.log(error);

}

navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div><img id="yourImg" src=""/><div>
```

Comment: I check that link's but i just take take picture from the gallery.

Comment: In the bottom of my answer I have a bit about using the camera plugin to select pictures from the gallery.

Comment: You talking about the `plugin camera`

Comment: Yes. See my answer. I have added how to install and use the camera plugin at the bottom.

Comment: Yes i check that, i find this [plugin camera example](http://www.offlineprogrammer.com/upload-images-app-storage-using-ionic-framework/)

Comment: So does it do what you want?

Comment: Yes, show image in div, i try to understand you say

Comment: So you want to pick an image from the gallery and then display that image in a <div>

Comment: Yes i try to do that

Comment: I have added a bit of extra JavaScript and HTML to the bottom of my answer. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i try to finish the project. I used the directives in my code, and try to adapt you code to my projct.

Comment: Sorry, i can't do it, i convert image to `Base64` and don't show nothing, look at this [link code](https://pastebin.com/CPr5nLcA)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142038/discussion-between-l-balsdon-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).